# Windows 10 unity mode

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, debian, vmware-workstation

I am running vmware workstation 11 on windows 10, and it seems Unity mode doesn't work.

I've tried both Debian (jessie and stretch) with gnome-fallback (metacity), kde, and xfce as well as Ubuntu 15.04 with xfce & gnome-fallback (metacity) as guests. Every time I tried to enter Unity i get the message

> The virtual machine cannot enter Unity mode. Check that Unity is supported for this guest operating system and that the latest version of VMware Tools is installed.

I have `open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-desktop` installed on all of them. I also ran the vmware-tools installer after to install all it's kernel modules and whatever else it does.

Comment: By Unity mode do you mean the VMWare feature or do you mean the desktop environment? If you mean the desktop environment, it seems there are a lot of issues with it and it's unlikely to work (see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/227712/vmware-unity-mode-with-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: I mean the vmware feature.

Comment: I'm not so clued up on the feature itself, but have you tried running `vmware-config-tools.pl`? There are a lot of people out there saying this worked for them - should be in the guest tools disc image.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, idk how I didn't find that on my own. Go ahead and answer the question and I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `vmware-config-tools.pl` should fix this - the issue may return on reboot, in which case you could automate the running of this script at startup, or find a way to better integrate the changes it makes.

Comment: thanks, just rebooted it a few times to make sure, but seems like the issue isn't returning. I'll award you the bounty as soon as I can :)

Comment: so this works just fine as long as I don't have any extra monitors plugged in, I made a post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/3jf7zi/vmware_unity_issue/).

Comment: Ahh damn. I'll respond on Reddit since it's more in my scope :)